# How to invoke anonymous functions in testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Below is Java code.

I need to cover the below function. I searched for many websites, but I still have no ideas. Is there any methods to cover the override anonymous classes?

```
  public static void addEnterListener(Text text, final String methodName, final Object callee) {
    text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.keyCode == '\r') {
      try {
        Method method = callee.getClass().getMethod(methodName, KeyEvent.class);
        method.invoke(callee, arg0);
      } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) { 
  }
});
}
```

Comment: take a look at the answers to this SO question: **[Access anonymous inner class variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3509801/839601)**

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to do that with annonymous classes.

You can refactorize your code so:

```
  public static void addEnterListener(Text text, final String methodName, final Object callee) {
    text.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
  }

  class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
      if (arg0.keyCode == '\r') {
        try {
          Method method = callee.getClass().getMethod(methodName, KeyEvent.class);
          method.invoke(callee, arg0);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) { 
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I am not allowed to change the addEnterListener, that really means no approach to invoke it??     Because I have  invoked the similar codes accidentally with a lot of error message. But, I still dont know how to cover these function

Answer (score 3):

Well, for THAT code, you could inject a mocked Text-object and fetch the keyListener after return and call keyReleased on this, e.g. using mockito

```
@Test
void doTest(){
  Text mock = mock(Text.class);
  StaticClass.addEnterListener(mock, ....);
  ArgumentCaptor<KeyListener> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(KeyListener.class);
  verify(mock).addKeyListener(captor.capture());
  KeyListener theListener = captor.getValue();

  theListener.keyReleased(...);
}
```

I did not test this, but this should be the way...
though i would encourage to refactor this...

Answer (score 0):

As a third option, refactor creation of the KeyListener into a getKeyListener method. Call that method from your test code to get a KeyListener to test. Also call it in addEnterListener to get the KeyListener to add.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, apparently we are not supposed to test anon class methods, according to a colleague ? We refactor code to named methods to accommodate testing.